# Sending GA4 event from Server Side PHP not working

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have a form completion event I want to send from the server side so I can validate and filter out spam first.  It works fine when send through javascript.

```
const measurement_id = `G-XXXXXXXXXX`;
const api_secret = `api_secret_key`;

fetch(`https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=${measurement_id}&api_secret=${api_secret}`, {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    client_id: '1552776741.1677766660',
    events: [{
      name: 'form_submission',
      params: {'form_name':'Send A Message',
      'is_lead':'Lead+Submission',
      'submission_url':'Unknown'},
    }]
  })
});
```

When I go to send it with PHP instead, it never makes it to GA4 but also does not return any kind of error message.

```
$measurement_id = 'G-XXXXXXXXXX';
$api_secret = 'api_secret_key';
$url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=" . $measurement_id . "&api_secret=" . $api_secret;

$data = array(
  'client_id' => '1552776741.1677766660', 
  'events' => array(
    'name' => 'form_submission', 
    'params' => array(
      'form_name' => 'Send A Message 2', 
      'is_lead' => 'Non-Lead Submission', 
      'submission_url' => 'Unknown'
    )
  )
);

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data)
  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$resp = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $resp;
```

Any insight into how to get this to process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `events` array structure is different.  You might want to look at that

Comment: Also, any reason for not using curl?  It would do a lot more error handling for you

Comment: `file_get_contents` won't tell you if the request failed with a 400 error or something. What does the echoed `$resp` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the PHP code that could be preventing the event from being sent to GA4:

1. The `events` array should contain an object with `name` and `params` properties, not just an array. This means you need to wrap the `name` and `params` in an object like this:

```
'events' => array(
    array(
      'name' => 'form_submission', 
      'params' => array(
        'form_name' => 'Send A Message 2', 
        'is_lead' => 'Non-Lead Submission', 
        'submission_url' => 'Unknown'
      )
    )
  )
```

2. The `Content-type` header should be set to `application/json` since the body is being sent as JSON.
3. You're using `http_build_query()` to encode the data, but it should be encoded as JSON instead. You can use `json_encode()` to do this:

```
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => json_encode($data)
  )
);
```

Here's the corrected code:

```
$measurement_id = 'G-XXXXXXXXXX';
$api_secret = 'api_secret_key';
$url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?measurement_id=" . $measurement_id . "&api_secret=" . $api_secret;

$data = array(
  'client_id' => '1552776741.1677766660', 
  'events' => array(
    array(
      'name' => 'form_submission', 
      'params' => array(
        'form_name' => 'Send A Message 2', 
        'is_lead' => 'Non-Lead Submission', 
        'submission_url' => 'Unknown'
      )
    )
  )
);

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/json",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => json_encode($data)
  )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$resp = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo $resp;
```

Make sure to replace `G-XXXXXXXXXX` with your actual measurement ID and `api_secret_key` with your actual API secret key.